# Font size in xsl-fo difference in browser?

Tags: html, pixel, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using apache FOP to generate pdf documents with common parameters:

- font-size: 10px
- font-family: Arial

The content pdf like as image below:
[image]
*pdf content*

Besides, I also build similar content using HTML tag (`<table>, <tr>, <td>, <div>,...`). However, on `HTML` page the characters are smaller than `PDF` page, even though I used the same `font-size` and `font-family` in both. What the difference with pixel between `xsl-fo` and `html`?
[image]
*Html content*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lengths in `px` can be unreliable because different software can have different ideas about the absolute size of a pixel.

In XSL-FO, `px` is implementation-dependent, but the Recommendation does recommend 1/92" or 1/72". See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#pixels

I haven't been able to find the size of a FOP pixel. (FWIW, AH Formatter defaults to 96 `px` per inch, but you can change it. See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-optset.html#pxpi)

Comment: Hi Tony, you're right, in xsl-fo (i'm using apache FOP), 1inch = 72px, but in browser (exp: chrome,..), it seem to 1inch = 96px